# How to force a specific region of an image to be totally white?

Tags: image-processing

I have an image `img`, and a region `iTrim` as below:-

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]
iTrim = ImageTrim[img, {{30, 150}, {230, 210}}]
```

[image]

My desired output is, an image of `img`, but all the region of `iTrim` would be totally white in color.

How can I get such an image?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did any of the **5 answers** satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one and all that, but one weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
{left, right, top, bottom} = {30, 230, h - 210, h - 150};

data = ImageData[img];
data[[top ;; bottom, left ;; right]] = {1, 1, 1};
Image[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

This is very short:

```
ImageSubtract[#, ImageAlign[#, iTrim]] &@img
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Graphics` to create a mask image:

```
mask = Rasterize[
  Style[Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{30, 150}, {230, 210}]}, 
    PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[img]}], 
    ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img], Background -> Black], 
   Antialiasing -> False]]
```

[image]

The important thing is that the Graphics has the same resolution as the source image and that it's not antialiased. Setting up the `Graphics` is always the same, so you can move it into a function:

```
makeMask[img_, shapes_] := 
 Rasterize[
  Style[Graphics[{White, shapes}, 
    PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[img]}], 
    ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img], Background -> Black], 
   Antialiasing -> False]]

mask = makeMask[img, Rectangle[{30, 150}, {230, 210}]]
```

And then just add that to the source image:

```
img + mask
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
ImageApply[# + Unitize @ Most @ #2 &, {img, ImageAlign[img, iTrim]}] (* or *)
ImageAdd[img, ImageApply[Unitize @ Most @ # &, ImageAlign[img, iTrim]]] (* or *)
ImageAdd[img, ImageMultiply[ImageAlign[img, iTrim, Background -> Black], 999]]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess we both thought of `ImageAlign` at the same time... (+1)

Comment: @Jens, thank you. Much cleaner version with  `ImageSubtract` doesn't work in v9 if the number of channels are unequal (or one of the images is single-channel.)

Answer (score 2):

I just found a clumsy solution. There may be a much more efficient one.

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]
loc = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = {{30, 150}, {230, 210}};
iTrim = ImageTrim[img, loc]

{w, h} = ImageDimensions@img
iTrimM = ImageMultiply[iTrim, 999]
iPad = ImagePad[iTrimM, {{x1, w - x2}, {y1, h - y2}}]
ImageAdd[img, iPad]
```